# In Java How to receive http and non http(udp,..etc)

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, websocket, serversocket

In my java application,i want to receive http and non http requests and process these requests.Please let me know how to do this through socket programming os is there any way to do in the Spring framework. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you run your application inside of some server like tomcat, or do you want to write a stand alone application?

Comment: Do you understand my question?

Comment: both are fine. i can able to run as standalone or some server.

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds like very broad, but I think [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) answers to your question. It provides an implementation of [EIP](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/) and provides many `protocol-specific adapters`, lile HTTP, TCP, JMS etc.

And, of course, everything is based on Spring foundation!